# How to account for @Observable Macro expansion when creating your own Peer Macro in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, macros, observation

I've made a macro called `Resettable` which creates a private constant initialised with the same value as the declaration the macro is attached to:

```swift
public struct ResettableMacro: PeerMacro {
    public static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax,
                                 providingPeersOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol,
                                 in context: some MacroExpansionContext)
    throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        guard let variableDecl = declaration.as(VariableDeclSyntax.self) else {
            print("Can only be applied to variable declarations") 
            return []
        }
        guard variableDecl.bindingSpecifier.text == "var" else {
            print("Can only be a variable")
            return []
        }
        guard variableDecl.bindings.allSatisfy({ $0.initializer != nil }) else {
            print("Must be an initialised stored property")
            return []
        }
        
        // abstracted extracting the identifier pattern and the initial value for clarity
        return zip(variableDecl.identifiers, variableDecl.values).map { name, value in
            "private let $\(raw: name) = \(raw: value)"
        }
    }
}
```

This works very well, **except** when I use `@Resettable` on a class marked with `@Observable`. When I do that I get the following error which I don't understand:

> 'self' used in property access '$_name' before 'self.init' call

```swift
@Observable
class Person { 
    @Resettable var name = "John Doe"
        // << error here due to @ObservationTracked
}
```

This is because the `@Observable` macro adds another declaration:

```swift
@Resettable  @ObservationIgnored private var _name  = "John Doe"
```

which is emitting this error.

I thought this wouldn't be a problem because `@Resettable` will only see "The original version of the declaration without expansions provided by others" *(from the "Expand on Swift macros" talk)*. Even if you consider what the `@Observable` macro is doing, it's creating one underscored property (`_name`), and creating accessors for the non-underscored version (`name`). Since in my macro implementation, an initialiser is **required**, the `name` property with a getter and setter would be skipped as there is no initialiser. Yet, I am still getting an error. In fact, I don't even understand what this error means and why it's coming.

I initially thought of skipping delcarations marked with `@ObservationTracked`, but this doesn't account for other macros that might expand similarly, nor if the `@ObservationTracked` macro's name changes.

I would love to know how I can account for the `@Observable` expansion in my macro in the simplest way.

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution for this?